# Flex Tree Display Custom Data - DataDescriptor?

Tags: apache-flex, tree

I am trying to have a tree display custom data that looks like this.

```
ID  DATA    PARENT  SORT
a   ...              10
aa  ...     a        10
ab  ...     a        20
b   ...              20
c   ...              30
```

It would look like this in xml

```
<root>
    <a>
        <aa/>
        <ac/>
    </a>
    <b/>
    <c/>
</root>
```

I don't want to translate it into XML. I want to tie in to Tree to have it display my data as a hierarchy. I've created a custom data descriptor (implements ITreeDataDescriptor2), and it doesn't quite work. It does display the nodes with the correct indentation, but it doesn't put the nodes inside of their parents

http://pastie.textmate.org/604675

[alt text http://files.seanhess.net/trees.png](http://files.seanhess.net/trees.png)

What do I need to implement / do to get this data to display? It seems like the problem is in the `getHierarchicalCollectionAdaptor` function, but I'm not really sure what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending DefaultDataDescriptor instead. In all likelihood you have a bug in your code. You will want to override the getChildren, hasChildren and isBranch methods.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was an error in how I implemented the getNodeDepth method. I originally thought the depth of the top level was 0 and coded accordingly. But the top level is 1, and making that change made the hierarchy display correctly.